# RealTek RTL8111/8168 ethernet controller, network keeps dropping off - Ubuntu 16.10 4.8.0-37

Tags: ethernet, 16.10, realtek

I seem to be having problems maintaining an internet connection while using the ethernet connection on my laptop, specifically that I can only keep a connection for roughly five minutes before it automatically cuts off for some reason.

Output of lsmod as follows:

```
lsmod | grep r816
r8168                 495616  0
```

So I believe I am using the correct driver. I have also run

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

Also I have made sure to blacklist the r8169 driver and removed it using

```
sudo sh -c 'echo blacklist r8169 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
rmmod r8169
```

Now, this is where it gets interesting/frustrating: My work PC is running Ubuntu 16.10 and kernel 4.8.0-37, exactly the same as my laptop. My PC also uses a Realtek RTL8111/8168 ethernet adapter, exactly the same as my laptop. The only difference? My desktop PC has absolutely no trouble at all with a wired connection! This completely baffles me.

Does anybody have any other ideas I could try? I am utterly flummoxed at this point, and although having a wired connection isn't the be-all, end-all for me, I would prefer it over wireless for my work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

D

Comment: There are lots of revisions of this adapter. It may be a hardware trouble too.

Comment: That was my thinking too. I've half a mind to bite the bullet and buy a usb>ethernet adapter, but my inner geek wants to win this battle.